# Auth0 Login in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, auth0

Hello I am trying to add Auth0 Login to my Xamarin forms Mobile Application,
I was following the Quick start and And came into a problem. where do i add this code

```
var client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
{
    Domain = "******.auth0.com",
    ClientId = "******"
}, this);
```

I am new to Xamarin and cannot figure out where to add it. I tried to add  it in a seperact file in  Service Folder But **Auth0.OidcClient.Android** is only installed to my android Project,i Tried to install on main project but it alwasys fails

Comment: Install `Auth0.OidcClient.Core` in your shared code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69086385/xamarin-build-failed-after-adding-auth0-oidcclient-android CAn u please look into this . I cant seems to get Auth0 to work

Comment: Why are you creating multiple questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auth0.OidcClient.Android latest version did not work for me So i used ***3.0.1***
So the steps i followed
Install **Auth0.OidcClient.Android 3.0.1** in Android project
In Mainproject create a IAuthService file(Interface)

```
 public interface IAuthService
{
    Task<LoginResult> Login();
    Task Logout();
}
```

Create a AuthenticationService class in Android project
Implement IAuthService,Making a Depandancy injunction

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Auth0.OidcClient;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AuthenticationService))]
namespace XamarinAuth02.Droid
{

    public class AuthenticationService
        : IAuthService
    {
        private Auth0Client _auth0Client;

        public AuthenticationService()
        {
            _auth0Client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
            {
                Domain = AuthConfig.Domain,
                ClientId = AuthConfig.ClientId
            });
        }
        public async Task<LoginResult> Login(new 
{ audience = AuthConfig.Audience })
        {
            LoginResult result = await _auth0Client.LoginAsync();
            return result;
        }

        public async Task Logout()
        {
            _ = await _auth0Client.LogoutAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

In Main Activity in android project
**LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask** is importent

```
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, Label = "XamarinAuth02", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]


[IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = "com.companyname.xamarinauth02",//package name
    DataHost = "Domain",
    DataPathPrefix = "/android/com.companyname.xamarinauth02ThisMyPackageName/callback")]

protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        ActivityMediator.Instance.Send(intent.DataString);
    }
```

Now u can create a obj of IAuthService and call login / logout
private readonly

```
IAuthService _authenticationService;

_authenticationService = DependencyService.Get<IAuthService>();
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loginresult = await _authenticationService.Login();
            if (loginresult.IsError)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Login Failed", "Okay");
            }
            else
            {
                await SecureStorage.SetAsync("accessToken", loginresult.AccessToken);
                await SecureStorage.SetAsync("UserName", loginresult.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value);
                IsLoggedIn = true;
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage(loginresult.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value));
            }

        }
```

Sorry For my Typing Hope this helps someone

Comment: Thank You!   I have been trying to make this work for days.  After reading this, and several posts with similar code, I couldn't get it to work.


Until I read this, ```In Main Activity in android project LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask is importent```

Now I would like to understand why that was important

Comment: so when you go to auth0 loginpage . This keep u in the same state and doesnot refresh back to ur loginpage. without this code after login insted of going to next line after login (ie to next page) it will reload login page